Links embedded in pdf of google calendar getting changed automatically from original intended url in android
I am facing this strange issue with google calendar links.
So, I have embedded a clickable url in a pdf. The expectation is when the pdf is shared to someone and they click on that object,it should open the calendar url in the format
Eg
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?dates=20241103T060000Z/20241103T110000Z&text=Reminder&location=India&details
However whenever they are clicking it they are being redirected to some other link in this format
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit/copy/MXE4ZWkxY3UxY202MXE1N3B1am9kZmZsNXQgbWFycmlhZ2UuaW52aXRlMDMx/ycmljMjg3QGdtYWxyzvbQ
Btw if my accounts or linked google  account opens,it works perfectly fine but not for others.
Additionaly, the event, the account, the calendar is made public.
Any idea how to solve it?
Including the action template in parameter also not working.

The url is modified randomly to prevent people reaching actual event but presented just as a reference.. so what should i do now? Any ideas?

This is the exact url(removing some obvious values) which is embedded in the link.
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?dates=20241103T060000Z/20241103T110000Z&text=Reminder&location=India&details    following any previous recommendations from other questions..so not where i am going wrong
